# Legal to mine bitcoin when on U.K. benefits?

Tags: united-kingdom, currency, cryptocurrency

I am a uk citizen lining in England who is currently on ESA benefits since I cannot work at the moment.

I understand that I am only allowed a certain amount of money in my name at a time and if I have more, my benefit income may be reduced.

If I were to spend some of the money on cloud mining in bitcoin, would that be legal? Would I have to declare it or affect my benefits etc.?

If someone knows the answer, please could they link their sources so I can read through them please?